# Cocos2d-iphone basic compile error

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I downloaded Cocos2d-iphone 0.99.5 and installed it using ./install-script

I then opened xcode and created a new cocos2d application. When I ran Build and Run it, gave the error  'There is no SDK with the name or path iphoneos'. Searching online I found a solution which said to change the Base SDK setting in Project Settings. I changed it to the Simulator of iphone os 3.1.2.

But now when I Build and Run, it gives me 217 errors. Most are: "float.h No such File or directory" or "stdarg.h No such file or directory"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to update Xcode to 3.2.5, with iOS 4.2. Check inside the Project Settings for cocos2d -- I believe the base SDK is up above 4.0, probably at 4.1 or 4.2, by now. If all of the items in the Frameworks folder are red, that means that the project is trying to link to a  higher SDK, and can't find anything.

Comment: Yup, simplying installing Xcode 3.2.5 corrects everything. Thanks.